# Hibernate UserType methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have implemented the UserType interface provided by Hibernate. It is working as expected.

But, I don't understand what the method `Object deepCopy(Object value)` does. Documentation of other methods of this interface like `assemble()`, `disassemble()` says "At the very least this method should perform a deep copy if the type is mutable"

So looked into the documentation provided by Hibernate and it says the following:

"Return a deep copy of the persistent state, stopping at entities and at collections. It is not necessary to copy immutable objects, or null values, in which case it is safe to simply return the argument."

I am not able to understand what is the meaning of "deep copy of persistent state". Could somebody please elaborate what is the purpose of deepCopy() method and what are possible implementations ?